# Why is my environment variable is partially set?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

1. My goal is to set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` for an user named `grid` which is just the traditional user name for hadoop.
2. My machine is a virtual machine deployed in VMware Workstation, 64bit CentOS7.
3. What I do:
   I edit the file that is supposed to change my user-specific environment variable, i.e. `~/.bash_profile`. Below is my code:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/home/grid/jdk
   export HADOOP_HOME=/home/grid/hadoop
   PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME:$JAVA_HOME
   export PATH
   ```
4. Very interestingly, when I log in as user `grid`, and I run `echo $HADOOP_HOME`, I get `/home/grid/hadoop`, but I get an nothing as response when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`, literally just nothing, an empty string or null, something like that. I run `cd $JAVA_HOME`, and I end up in home directory.
5. I tried changing the JDK folder, it didn't work. I tried the same code on another machine, it worked. I put the code in `/etc/profile` and log in as root, same thing happened, good for `echo $HADOOP_HOME` but no response for `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: is a later part of that file unsetting JAVA_HOME?

Comment: But that's all the code I put in .bash_profile, why would it unset JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I don't know what else is in your .bash_profile, so I asked.

Comment: I see,  that's a good point. I thought about it too. Could it be some other file other than ./bash_profile that has  code in it and unsets JAVA_HOME?

Comment: You say you modified `.bash_profile`, then logged in as `grid`. Was the `.bash_profile` that you modified in the home directory of `grid` or of some other user?

Comment: Is there anything in `~/.bashrc` that unsets `JAVA_HOME` or otherwise calls out to a script that unsets it? (If you have a `~/.bashrc` file, put something like `test -t 1 && echo "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME"` as the first line _and also_ as the last line. It'll print twice but you'll get to see if it's being reset betweentimes.)

Comment: @roaima, no my ```~/.bashrc``` is empty

Comment: @Kusalananda no, I make sure that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an item of note on `$PATH`.  You have the `JAVA_HOME` set to the `jdk` directory, but for the `PATH`, you need to make that `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.

Second, if you need these variables to be available to non-interactive scripts, you may want to put them in `~/.bashrc`, since `~/.bash_profile` is read by interactive logins only.

In fact, the actual order in which (login shell) profiles are read is:

1. `/etc/profile`

then:

2. `~/.bash_profile` (On CentOS, if `-f ~/.bashrc`, sources `~/.bashrc`)
3. `~/.bash_login`
4. `~/.profile` (On Ubuntu, if `-n $BASH_VERSION`, sources `~/.bashrc`)

**EDIT:  If one of these files is found, further files are not processed unless explicitly sourced**

Non-login shells (by default) only look for `~/.bashrc`.

So, depending on how you're executing `bash`, you may not even be reading the profile you've added these lines to.  Are you executing `sudo -u grid bash`, or `su grid`, or `su - grid`, or initiating a new ssh session each time you test?  Some of those options may not trigger an interactive login bash shell.

So check each of the files listed above, and see if any of them are unsetting, or resetting the `JAVA_HOME` variable.  Then try adding the lines to the end of `~/.profile`, which is the last file sourced by a login shell.

For debugging purposes you can add messages to the profile to make sure it's getting set right, too.

`~/.profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/grid/jdk
echo "DEBUG: .profile: JAVA_HOME is [$JAVA_HOME]"
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/grid/hadoop
echo "DEBUG: .profile: HADOOP_HOME is [$HADOOP_HOME]"
PATH=$HADOOP_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
echo "DEBUG: .profile: PATH is [$PATH]"
export PATH
```

This will cause 3 lines of output when you login to an interactive login shell, and the values between the brackets will make it easy to see if the values are being set to begin with.  If you see that `JAVA_HOME` *is* being set when `~/.profile` is sourced, but is not set when the shell becomes interactive, then you know you need to keep following the login process to determine where the value is changing.

Comment: I put the code as above in the file ~/.profile, and run su - grid, but nothing returned, as opposed to 3 lines as you said above. That's very frustrating..

Comment: That is very strange.  Are you certain the the `grid` user has `/bin/bash` as their shell?  And not `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/sh` or something else?

Comment: OOh.  It seems that files are only processed in the order above until a file is found.  So if you have a `~/.bash_profile`, add your lines to the end of that, or consolidate all your rules into one file.

Comment: Interestingly, it worked after I add it to ~/.bash_profile. But I don't understand why? There is no essential difference between your code and mine except that you added the debug line and bin to each of the HOME variable.

Comment: Well, it seems if you have a `~/.bash_profile`, it gets processed and the other files are not read.  Subsequent files (`.bash_login`, `.profile`) are only read if the file before them in the list doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, but I had ~/.bash_profile at the very beginning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64261/discussion-between-sam-chan-and-tim-kennedy).

Comment: `.profile` should never source `.bashrc`; the former is intended for use by *any* POSIX-compatible shell, while `.bashrc` could contain `bash`-specific code. (It's OK to source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`, though.) `.bash_login` is typically never used; it exists to make former users of `csh` more comfortable. `.bash_profile` is a correct place for environment variables, as they will be inherited by any child shells.

Comment: Well, the `/etc/skel/.profile` file on Ubuntu by default tests for `$BASH_VERSION` and if it's found, sources `.profile`.   On, CentOS, the `/etc/skel/.bash_profile` tests for `~/.bashrc` and sources it if found.